# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) when trying to create a DNS message with scapy + code returnes nothing when used in the CMD

Tags: python, scapy, unpack

I'm trying to create a function that does a DNS query using Scapy. but i stumped upon an error at the creation of the query.

This is the my code:

```
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, UDP
from scapy.layers.dns import DNS, DNSQR
from scapy.all import sr1

message = IP(dst="8.8.8.8") / UDP(dport=53, sport=8280) / DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname=target), iface="eth1")
result = sr1(message, verbose=10)
print(result[DNS].summary())
```

I also noticed that my code returns no IP's at all when i execute it in the CMD, It doesn't have a connection to the problem a head i believe, but it's a problem non the less that you could potentially fix as well.

Thanks for everyone :D

IMPORTANT: I was able to fix the problem. it seems that Scapy 2.4.2
is bugged. I used it in PyCharm 2018 and scapy had a problem with recognizing
the interface's I gave him even though they should be recognized as valid interfaces. To fix the problem just downgrade your version to 2.4.0 for example and it should work again! :D

Comment: what line of code throws the exception? mind sharing the full stack trace?

Comment: Hello sir! I managed to fix the problem by my self. it seems that Scapy 2.4.2 is bugged. the problem happened because Scapy couldn't recognize the Interface i gave him even though it was shown when i wrote "ifaces". I fixes the problem by downgrading my scapy to 2.4.0.

Comment: good to hear that :) I'd suggest you self-answer your question so future users with the same problem know how you eventually solved it.